# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el max() de una tabla derivada?

Tags: mysql

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de MySQL en donde debo hacer las consultas correspondientes para obtener el nombre del ganador de una partida de tenis según una tabla en donde se alamcena el id del jugador, el id de la partida, el número de set y su correspondiente puntutacion.
Hasta ese punto no tengo ningún problema para obtener el nombre del jugador junto con la suma de las puntuaciones de todos sus sets (para saber qué jugador anotó más puntos).
El código que utilizo para obtener esos datos es el siguiente, el nombre de mi base de datos es grand_slam:

```
select j.apellido as nombre, sum(s.puntos) as total
from 
    grand_slam.modalidad m, grand_slam.fase f,
    grand_slam.torneo t, grand_slam.partida p,
    grand_slam.partida_jugador pj, grand_slam.jugador j,
    grand_slam.set_individual s
where 
    m.modalidad = "Individual masculino"
    and f.fase = "Cuartos de final"
    and t.nombre = "Roland Garros"
    and year(t.fecha_inicio) = 1979 
    and t.id_mod = m.id_mod
    and p.id_fase = f.id_fase
    and p.id_torneo = t.id_torneo
    and pj.id_partida = p.id_partida
    and j.id_jugador = pj.id_jugador
    and s.id_jugador = j.id_jugador
group by apellido
```

Al ejecutar este código obtengo este resultado, que es correcto:

```
+------------+-------+
| nombre     | total |
+------------+-------+
| Connors    |    23 |
| Gerulaitis |    14 |
+------------+-------+
```

Como necesito obtener el nombre del ganador pensé que podría utilizar esta consulta dentro de otra en donde solo obtenga la tupla con max(total), e hice esto:

```
select nombre from(
     select j.apellido as nombre, sum(s.puntos) as total
    from 
         grand_slam.modalidad m, grand_slam.fase f,
         grand_slam.torneo t, grand_slam.partida p,
         grand_slam.partida_jugador pj, grand_slam.jugador j,
         grand_slam.set_individual s
     where 
         m.modalidad = "Individual masculino"
         and f.fase = "Cuartos de final"
         and t.nombre = "Roland Garros"
         and year(t.fecha_inicio) = 1979 
         and t.id_mod = m.id_mod
         and p.id_fase = f.id_fase
         and p.id_torneo = t.id_torneo
         and pj.id_partida = p.id_partida
         and j.id_jugador = pj.id_jugador
         and s.id_jugador = j.id_jugador
     group by apellido
) as Resultado
where Resultado.total = (select max(total) from Resultado);
```

Intento seleccionar solo el nombre de la 'nueva tabla' que llamé Resultado que tuviera el valor maximo para total, pero al ejecutarla recibo el error:

```
Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected
[Done] Finished MySQL query.
```

No se porque me marca ese error :(
O no se si exista otra forma más fácil de obtener el maximo valor de un atributo de una tabla creada en una subconsulta.

Comment: Pero ese error que muestras no tiene nada que ver con la consulta, ahi dice que no has seleccionado una base de datos :(

Comment: Es lo que no entiento, porque según yo le puse el nombre Resultado a la tabla de la subconsulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías intentar con utilizando `limit 1` y `order desc`, espero haber comprendiedo el contexto de tu pregunta.

example:

```
select nombre,total from(
     select j.apellido as nombre, sum(s.puntos) as total
    from 
         grand_slam.modalidad m, grand_slam.fase f,
         grand_slam.torneo t, grand_slam.partida p,
         grand_slam.partida_jugador pj, grand_slam.jugador j,
         grand_slam.set_individual s
     where 
         m.modalidad = "Individual masculino"
         and f.fase = "Cuartos de final"
         and t.nombre = "Roland Garros"
         and year(t.fecha_inicio) = 1979 
         and t.id_mod = m.id_mod
         and p.id_fase = f.id_fase
         and p.id_torneo = t.id_torneo
         and pj.id_partida = p.id_partida
         and j.id_jugador = pj.id_jugador
         and s.id_jugador = j.id_jugador
     group by apellido
) as Resultado
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! es justo lo que necesitaba pero no se me había ocurrido